# Cannot append DOM element to DIV node: Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using the DOM parser I parsed a string , and then tried to append the object to a container, like so:

```
      var newCategory = 
        "<div class=\"column-expenses-left\" id=\"newCategory"+ expenseCategoryCssName +"\">" +
          "<hr />" +
          "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">" +
            "<?php echo $budgetExpense[\'ExpenseCategory\'][\'cssName\']; ?>&nbsp;" +
            "<span>" +
            "<a href=\"#\" class=\"delete-category\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"/theme/all/img/Trash_can_small.png\" style=\"width: 15px; height: 15px; float: right;\" id=\"\" alt=\"Delete\"/></a>"+
            "</span>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<hr />" +
          "<p class=\"pointer\" style=\"text-align: center;\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"/theme/all/img/add_to_yours.png\" style=\"display: inline-block;\" /></p>" +
        "</div> <!-- column-expenses-left -->";

      // get the object to append to 
      var stack = document.getElementById('newCategories');

      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var newNode = parser.parseFromString(newCategory, "text/xml");

      stack.appendChild(newNode);
```

However I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'.
```

I don't quite understand what is happening here? Is there a way to use the parser so that it creates a node of type DIV instead? Is this even a good idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't append document nodes (the result of `parseFromString`). Instead take the child of the document object and append it:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var newNode = parser.parseFromString(newCategory, "text/xml");
stack.appendChild(newNode.documentElement);
```

Note, that your HTML is not XML-compliant so you might get errors parsing it. In this case make sure you fix them (like duplicated `alt` attribute, `&nbsp;` entities).

However, in your case I doubt you need to parse XML at all. You can just append entire HTML string in the first place. For example like this:

```
var stack = document.getElementById('newCategories');
stack.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newCategory);
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. The little error is that in parser you are indicating that is `text/xml` and provide HTML code.

So just tell to the parser that is HTML not XML.

```js
var newNode = parser.parseFromString(newCategory, "text/html");
```

Comment: I know it's been years since you posted your answer, but your answer fixed my problem. Thanks