# Dynamically adding content to table using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, html-parsing

I'm trying to add as many rows as users I have in my database to a table. I'm getting the users' info from the backend via ajax request, then when the response (JSON) arrive my code pass it to I silly template I'd created using [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#template).

After underscore rendered the template this is what i got:

```
<tr data-id="29">
    <td>email@themail.ma</td>

    <td>
        <ul style="display:inline-block; padding-left:0; margin-bottom:0">
            <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <td>Activo</td>

    <td>No caduca</td>

    <td>
        <span data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar usuario">
            <a class="icon-trash" href="#" role="button"
               data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#js-confirm-modal"
               data-action="js-del-user"
               data-msg="Desea eliminar el usuario?"></a>
        </span>

        <span data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cambiar contraseña">
            <a class="icon-key" href="#" role="button"
               data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#js-confirm-modal"
               data-action="js-chg-pass"
               data-msg="Cambiar contraseña del usuario?"></a>
        </span>

        <span data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Bloquear usuario">
            <a class="icon-lock" href="#" role="button"
               data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#js-confirm-modal"
               data-action="js-block-user"
               data-msg="Desea bloquear el usuario?"></a>
        </span>

        <span data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Desbloquear usuario">
            <a class="icon-lock-open" href="#" role="button"
               data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#js-confirm-modal"
               data-action="js-unblock-user"
               data-msg="Desea desbloquear el usuario?"></a>
        </span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

So far so good, but when I do something like this:

```
tbody.innerHTML = html;

// or 

let parseHTML = function(str) {
  var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
  tmp.body.innerHTML = str;
  return tmp.body.children;
};

parseHTML(html);  // and then adding the returned codes to my tbody
```

It just looses the html table format (td, tr tags, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jaredgorski I realized why the html code was losing the formating, so this is the solution best fit my problem so far. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
function convert2Element (strHTML) {
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
    table.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = strHTML;
    return table.querySelector('tbody tr');
}
```

Then I can append the returned value like and treat it like the object it is.

Answer (score 2):

I often use template literals for this, constructing a long string of HTML using the `+=` operator and then using `document.innerHTML` to append the final HTML string to my page.

A simple example might look like this:

```js
const helloWorlds = {
  spanish: '¡Hola Mundo!',
  polish: 'Witaj świecie!',
  french: 'Bonjour le monde!'
}

const helloWorldsKeys = Object.keys(helloWorlds);

let listMarkup = '';

for (let i = 0; i < helloWorldsKeys.length; i++) {
  listMarkup += '<li class="listItem">' + helloWorlds[helloWorldsKeys[i]] + '</li>';
}

const myList = document.getElementById("list");

myList.innerHTML = listMarkup;
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Of course, you can also use `appendChild` to construct the list bit by bit in the client rather than adding the whole list at once. This might look like:

```js
const myList = document.getElementById("list");

const helloWorlds = {
  spanish: '¡Hola Mundo!',
  polish: 'Witaj świecie!',
  french: 'Bonjour le monde!'
}

const helloWorldsKeys = Object.keys(helloWorlds);

for (let i = 0; i < helloWorldsKeys.length; i++) {
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.classList.add('listItem');
  listItem.innerHTML = helloWorlds[helloWorldsKeys[i]];
  myList.appendChild(listItem);
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example using a table:

```js
const myTableBody = document.getElementById("my-table-body");

const helloWorlds = {
  spanish: '¡Hola Mundo!',
  polish: 'Witaj świecie!',
  french: 'Bonjour le monde!'
}

const helloWorldsKeys = Object.keys(helloWorlds);

for (let i = 0; i < helloWorldsKeys.length; i++) {

  // create a table row element
  let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');

  // create a table cell (td) element
  let listItem = document.createElement('td');
  listItem.classList.add('listItem');

  // add content to table cell element
  listItem.innerHTML = helloWorlds[helloWorldsKeys[i]];

  // append table cell to table row
  tableRow.appendChild(listItem);

  // append table row to table body
  myTableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>Hello World!</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="my-table-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Regarding your specific application, check out this answer if you want to explore creating HTML documents and appending their contents to other HTMl documents: [Cannot append DOM element to DIV node: Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643368/cannot-append-dom-element-to-div-node-uncaught-hierarchyrequesterror-failed-to)

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically add content to my table, the problem is when I try to parse the long string to HTML

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying about the table. This should work if you're dynamically adding content on page load, though for realtime updates (without a pageload) you'll either need event listeners, a scheduler, or some sort of framework. Let me experiment and update my answer

Comment: @Nestor I've updated my example to show how you can use `appendChild` with a table. Does this help?

Comment: Also, just to note, there's no need to parse the HTML unless you're parsing for some security purpose or to convert from XML.

Comment: take a look at the table row (<tr></tr>) I've posted in my question. I'm trying to add that one and others I will generate with underscore.js. I know how to dynamically add content to DOM, I would like to just append what I've got from underscore.js the same way.

Comment: I don’t understand why you need to create an entire HTML document with your snippet of HTML (which isn’t really parsing it, so parseHTML is an inaccurate name) and then append that document to the DOM. If you validate/trust the data in your database, you should be able to just generate a string and add it or append it element by element. As long as you’re formatting the table properly, it won’t lose it’s formatting. That’s why the HTML you’re passing to createHTMLDocument is losing its formatting: because you’re creating a whole document that starts with <tr> tags that aren’t in a <table>.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why it's losing the formatting. I was following [this](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#parse_html) code to avoid using jQuery, now I guess I have to refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that you're using `tbody.innerHTML = html;` instead of `tbody.innerHTML += html;`, when you use `+=` operator you keep the old HTML, if you use `=` you replace the old HTML with the new HTML

Comment: I think it would be better to use tbody.appendChild(html) than +=